# after modifying the functions in a python script in sublime and saved, function employed is not updated in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-import, jupyter-notebook

This is a general question so codes not included here.

Essentially, I wrote python functions that I need to use in sublime and make sure I have saved after every modification. A jupyter notebook is running along side while I am making changes to the python file.

The problem is, as I intend to do debugging within the jupyter notebook, even though I ran the import after every modification of the python file, the effect of the modification does not show up in the jupyter notebook.

Can anyone tell me why is this? Do I have to shut down the localhost everytime to import the most recent version of the python file? Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If a module has already been imported, importing it again won't reread the file from disk.  You would have to use `reload(module)`.  (See more information about similar issues [here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart).)  It's not totally clear from your statement if that's the source of your problem but it's a reasonable guess.